# Prove or give a counterexample: if $U_1, U_2, W$ are subspaces of $V$ such that $U_1 + W = U_2 + W$, then $U_1 = U_2$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have read the counterexample [here](http://linearalgebras.com/1c.html)

But why the following not work?

Let $u_1 \in U_1, u_2 \in U_2, w \in W$, then $u_1 + w = u_2 + w$, and $u_1 = u_2$

Does it follow that $U_1 = U_2$?

And I actually don't understand how someone can  come up with the counterexample? How they know the setting?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have assumed that the $w \in W$ must be the same, but this is not true in general.

If we know that $x \in U_1+W=U_2+W$, we can write $x=u_1 + w_1$  and $x=u_2+w_2$ but $w_1$ and $w_2$ need not be equal where here $u_i \in U_i, w_i \in W$.

In the solution that you have shared, we have $U_1+W = U_2+W=\mathbb{R}^2$ but $U_1 \ne U_2$.

$$(0,-1)+(0,1) \in U_1 +W$$
$$(0,0)+(0,0) \in U_2+W$$

but $(0,-1) \ne (0,0)$. Here $w_1 \ne w_2$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a different counterexample: let $U_1=\{(a,0):a\in\mathbb R\}, U_2=\{(a,a):a\in\mathbb R\}$ and $W=\{(0,a):a\in\mathbb R\}$.

Then $U_1+W=\mathbb R^2=U_2+W$, but $U_1\neq U_2$.